# How to select users that meet 2 requirements from the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to answer the following question. I need to select users who have listened to both track 1 and track 2 in the Track column. For some reason I am completely lost in how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You could count the number of relevant tracks each user listened to:

```
SELECT   user_id
FROM     mytable
WHERE    track IN ('track_1', 'track_2')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT track) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Another question. What if I wanted to get the release date for each individual track. Would I use the min function?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the ways:

```
SELECT user_id from TABLE_NAME 
WHERE track = 'track_1' AND 
           user_id IN 
           (SELECT user_id from TABLE_NAME where track = 'track_2');
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only two you could also use GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM t
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT track) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can probably go more simplistic than needing a where exists subquery.

```
Select userID
from yourtable
where Track in ('Track 1','Track 2')
group by userid
having count(1) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This works?

```
SELECT UserId
FROM YourTable
WHERE Track in ('track_1','track_2')
group by UserId
Having  count(distinct Track) > 1;
```